# PersianCalendar can't convert year/month/31(day) to Gregorian date

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, persian, datetime-conversion

I am trying to convert persianDate to standarddate .

```
public DateTime ConvertPersianToEnglish(string persianDate)
{
    string[] formats = { "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy/M/d", "yyyy/MM/d", "yyyy/M/dd" };
    DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(persianDate, formats,
                                      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
    PersianCalendar persian_date = new PersianCalendar();
    DateTime dt = persian_date.ToDateTime(d1.Year, d1.Month, d1.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return dt;
}
```

The Persiandate has formats like this: 1392/10/12(Year/month/day)

In my application i am trying to convert Year/month/31 to standard time but i got this error :

```
{System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExactMultiple(String s, String[] formats, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
```

The exactly value that i get the error is 1393/04/31.6 months in Iran have `31` days in month .

In the main i have this code :

```
 static void Main()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
           // Application.Run(new aaaa.Form1() );
            Application.Run(new frmLogin());
        }
```

Comment: `DateTime` is _Gregorian calender_ by default. What is your `CurrentCulture`? I suspect your date separator is not `/`, that's why you get an exception even if your string and format matches. If you change it to `InvariantCulture` for exmaple, it will be ok.

Comment: I don't know what s the currentcultrure how can i find that?

Comment: You can check your [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) of your program.

Comment: @SonerGönül I update my post as you can see my CurrentUICulture  is fa-IR.i changed it to InvariantCulture  but same error

Comment: Not `CurrentUICulture`, I asked `CurrentCulture`. They are different. For `InvariantCulture`, it works on me. `string[] formats = { "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy/M/d", "yyyy/MM/d", "yyyy/M/dd" }; DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact("1392/10/12", formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);`

Comment: i think this is very beautiful bug :) becuse is work for 1393/01/31 and it dos not work for 1393/02/31 and work for 1393/03/31 and not work for 1393/04/31!!!

Comment: So why @EmranSadeghi?

Comment: @EmranSadeghi the error thrown by             DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(persianDate, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

Comment: @EmranSadeghi This is not a bug because there is no dates like `1393/02/31` and `1393/04/31` on _Gregorian calender_. That's why isn't possible to parse a date which doesn't exist.

Comment: @SonerGönül in persian we have such dates ,so how we can change them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `new CultureInfo("fa-IR").Calendar` is set to `GregorianCalendar` by default in .NET framework and can't be changed to `PersianCalendar` without using the reflection. [more info here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32096/How-to-Set-PersianCalendar-to-CultureInfo)

So don't use `DateTime.ParseExact` for parsing a Persian date and try the following method instead:

```
   using System;
   using System.Globalization;
   using System.Linq;

    public static DateTime PersianDateToGregorianDate(string pDate)
    {
        var dateParts = pDate.Split(new[] { '/' }).Select(d => int.Parse(d)).ToArray();
        var hour = 0;
        var min = 0;
        var seconds = 0;
        return new DateTime(dateParts[0], dateParts[1], dateParts[2],
                            hour, min, seconds, new PersianCalendar());
    }
```

It works fine with `PersianDateToGregorianDate("1393/02/31")`

Comment: Thank you dear friend ,as you said i found something that proves your idea http://devnet.kentico.com/forums/f45/fp4/t29675/problem-with-convert-datetime-to-persian

Comment: But vahid what should i do ?S i know you are from Iran like me ,and i have a project that i am using PersianCalendar ,and i couldn't change anything so any idea i will be appreciate

Comment: I use this link but i got an error :The type initializer for 'PersianCulture.PersianCultureHelper' threw an exception.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the alternative method.

Comment: Thank you it works ,so what is the different between my method and your method ?could you please explain in more details ?

Comment: Here we are setting `new PersianCalendar()` explicitly. It doesn't depend on the user's culture settings or a calendar bug in `new CultureInfo("fa-IR")`.